# i have trouble appending something in js inside a for loop

Tags: javascript

I have this error:

> script.js:41 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties
> of null (reading 'append')     at script.js:41:12

in the below code

```
const form = document.querySelector("d-flex");
const glass = document.getElementById("glass");
const select = document.getElementById("episod-select");



const episodes = async () => {
//  ? trying to bring the api to website and making a select tag for it
const res = await axios.get("https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/5/episodes");
return res;
};




const data = episodes().then((res) => {
console.log(res);
for (let i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++) {
  const ses = res.data[i].season;
  const epi = res.data[i].number;
  const option = document.createElement("option");
  option.innerText = `S0${ses}E0${epi}`;
  select.append(option);
//! the error is right here ^^
}
});
```

Comment: Is there an element with id `episod-select` in your code?

Comment: That error tells you that `select` is undefined. Are you sure your selector is correct? Perhaps its id is `episode-select` instead?